# Remove whitespace near a character using regex in a long text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

How do I delete one or mores white spaces near a character in a long text. I do not want to remove other white spaces which are not present adjacent to the matching string. I only want to remove all white spaces next to the matching character and not all white spaces of the input string. For example:

```
[text][space][space]![space][text]                should result in [text]![text]
[text][space][space]![space][space][space][text]  should result in [text]![text]
[text][space]![space][space][text]                should result in [text]![text]
[text][space]![space][text]                       should result in [text]![text]
[text]![space][space][text]                       should result in [text]![text]
[text][space][space]![text]                       should result in [text]![text]
[text][space][space]!                             should result in [text]!
![space][space][text]                             should result in ![text]
```

The code I am going to write is:

```
for (int i = 0 to length of string)
{
 if (string[i] == character)  //which is the desired character "!"
 {
  int location = i+1;
  //remove all whitespace after the character till a non-whitespace character
  //is found or string ends
  while (string[location] == whitespace)
  {
   string[location].replace(" ", "");
   location++;
  }

  int location = i-1;
  //remove all whitespace before the character till a non-whitespace character
  //is found or string ends
  while (string[location] == whitespace)
  {
   string[location].replace(" ", "");
   location--;
  }
 }
}
```

Is there a better way of removing whitespaces near a character using Regex?

UPDATE:  I do not want to remove other white spaces which are not present adjacent to the matching string. For example:

```
some_text[space]some_other_text[space][space]![space]some_text[space]some_other_text 
is
 some_text[space]some_other_text!some_text[space]some_other_text
```

Comment: `string.Replace(" ","")` ?

Comment: @I4V No, I do not want to remove whitespaces not present adjacent to the matching string

Comment: @DGibbs Please read the update to the question. I do not want to remove other white spaces which are present not adjacent to the matching string.

Comment: @dgibbs Please read the update to the question. I do not want to remove other white spaces which are not present adjacent to the matching string.

Comment: Do you want to keep the line break at the end? I ask because that's also a white-space character.

Comment: @tim-schmelter Thanks for your reply. Christoph's code working well as of now.

Comment: @ComputerUser: I'm just asking because there might be a more efficient approach on large strings which uses string methods (or/and a `StringBuilder)`. Then it's important to know what should happen with the line breaks if the `"!"` is at the beginning or end of a line.
It's also good to know what Christoph's approach does if somebody else want to use it in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                 "whitespace.";
string pattern = "\\s*!\\s*";
string replacement = "!";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/xwewhkd1.aspx

Comment: I do not want to remove other white spaces which are present not adjacent to the matching string. For example: some_text[space]some_other_text[space][space]![space]some_text[space]some_other_text is some_text[space]some_other_text!some_text[space]some_other_text

Comment: Please read the update to the question. I do not want to remove other white spaces which are not present adjacent to the matching string.

Comment: Now it matches only whitespace before and after "!"

Comment: ohh. ok. thanks. Other users were not clear. So, I updated everywhere.